# Why does union & inner struct add padding?

Tags: c, padding, unions

On amd64, the following struct has a size of 16 bytes:

```
typedef struct _my_struct {
    void *a;
    UINT32 b;
    UINT16 c;
    UINT8 d;
    UINT8 e;
} my_struct;
```

But when I put the first three variable in a union as such, the size goes to 24. Why?

```
typedef struct _my_struct {
    union {
        struct {
            void *a;
            UINT32 b;
            UINT16 c;
        } my_inner;
        struct {
            void **f;
        } my_inner2;
    }
    UINT8 d;
    UINT8 e;
} my_struct;
```

Comment: The union is irrelevant. It's the inner struct which induces padding.

Comment: This is an oversimplified example for my problem. Of course in my real struct I have multiple things in the union.

Comment: Why would you introduce a `union` of 1 thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're creating a new struct type (`my_inner`). The compiler adds padding to this struct which makes its size go to 16 bytes (for amd64). Then it adds padding to the outer struct type (`my_struct`), which makes its size grow to 24 bytes.

Comment: Would there be any perf issues to packing the inner struct?

Comment: I don't believe so, since all members will still be naturally aligned for their type. But as always you should profile if you want to know for sure.

Comment: @NickBanks The compiler adds padding at the end of the structure so it is compatible with the same structure in an array.

Comment: @Persixty Why isn't the compiler smart enough to know this struct can't be in an array as it is, and just drop the padding?

Comment: @NickBanks Because it is specified that the structure will be laid out the same wherever it appears. Otherwise you'd get into trouble copying things around. There is method in this madness!

Comment: @Persixty The compiler will also add padding between members if necessary for them to be naturally aligned. The array case is a corner case of this: trailing padding is added to ensure that the first member is always aligned in an array of the struct. I was only talking about internal padding because since the inner struct doesn't have a tag, you can't make an array out of it.

Comment: @SamuelPeter It will. But that won't normally mean regrouping a structure like this will inflate the size. Remember the first member is always aligned.

Comment: @Persixty Yes in this case there is already no internal padding because all members are aligned even without padding, the only padding is at the end. So packing the struct will probably not affect performance

Comment: @SamuelPeter Agreed but not compliant to omit it.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the simplest solution to not increasing the overall size was to do the following:

```
typedef struct _my_struct {
    union {
        struct {
            void *a;
            UINT32 b;
            UINT16 c;
        } my_inner;
        struct {
            void **f;
        } my_inner2;
        struct {
            UCHAR __PADDING[sizeof(void*) + sizeof(UINT32) + sizeof(UINT16)];
            UINT8 d;
            UINT8 e;
        };
    }
} my_struct;
```

It's not pretty, but it achieves what I wanted, without having to pack anything.